# Any picture that I took does saves on my sd card but unable to view it unless rebooted

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdcard, android-file

Any pictures that I took does not appears in the gallery and even in the sd card, but it saves nonetheless.  All I need to do is to reboot the system and there it is.

Here's my current code:

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;

        try 
        {
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "myCaptured");

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) 
            {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) 
                {
                    Log.d("myCaptured", "Oops! Failed create " + "myCaptured" + " directory");
                }
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

            String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(path, System.currentTimeMillis()));
            outStream.write(arg0);
            outStream.close();

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            VuzixCamera.super.onBackPressed();
        }

        camera.startPreview();
    }};
```

Comment: You have to invoke the media scanner on the new file. Just one code line will do. Just 'google' for exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html) to get the file indexed, before it will be visible to the Gallery app, MTP clients (e.g., Windows desktops), etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
Uri imageFileUri = getContentResolver().insert(
    Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
try {
  OutputStream imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(
      imageFileUri);
  imageFileOS.write(data);
  imageFileOS.flush();
  imageFileOS.close();

  Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Saved JPEG!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  t.show();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  t.show();
}
camera.startPreview();
```

}}

Also, provide it in your manifest:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

-----Use above code it will save the image in SD card-----

Comment: Yes, i got your problem the issue is that when you are using call back function it is called in a seperate thread which take some time to write the image bytes on gallery, which is not provided in your case. So just use the above code it will do for you.